# Weather widget using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a weather widget using react but now I am finding I need to extend it so the default city is London when the page reloads (i.e The temperature value of london will always show when the page reloads)

an example can be seen here: https://master.dnlbz1v7c5k84.amplifyapp.com/weather

Currently you have to type in the city to retrieve the location temperature

my code is as follows:

import React, { useState } from 'react';

```
const api = {
    key: 'mykey',
    base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/'
}

function App() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  
    const search = evt => {
      if (evt.key === "Enter") {
        fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(result => {
            setWeather(result);
            setQuery('');
            console.log(result);
          });
      }
    }
  
    const dateBuilder = (d) => {
      let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
      let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  
      let day = days[d.getDay()];
      let date = d.getDate();
      let month = months[d.getMonth()];
      let year = d.getFullYear();
  
      return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
    }
  
    return (
      <div className={(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? ((weather.main.temp > 16) ? 'app warm' : 'app') : 'app'}>
        <main>
          <div className="search-box">
            <input 
              type="text"
              className="search-bar"
              placeholder="Search..."
              onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
              value={query}
              onKeyPress={search}
            />
          </div>
          {(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? (
          <div>
            <div className="location-box">
              <div className="location">{weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}</div>
              <div className="date">{dateBuilder(new Date())}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="weather-box">
              <div className="temp">
                {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}°c
              </div>
              <div className="weather">{weather.weather[0].main}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          ) : ('')}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```

I was wondering if there is a quick way to set the value state to London so that it shows on page load?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a default value to your query & use `useEffect` to trigger search after it renders for the first time

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [query, setQuery] = useState('London'); // provide a default value
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

const fetchResult = () => {
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        setWeather(result);
        setQuery('');
        console.log(result);
      });
}

const search = evt => {
  if (evt.key === "Enter") {
    fetchResult();
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  // search once after first render
  fetchResult();
}, []) // no dependency: execute it once after first render
```